# Where to find ListTile theme colors

Tags: flutter

While trying to combine Rows, Columns and ListTile, I cannot find the right colors for my icons. In the following example there are three icons in a Row, and one in a ListTile. Icons in `Row(Expanded())` containers are black, while an Icon in `ListTile()` is gray. I would like all icons to be gray, but I cannot find that color in a `Theme.of(context)`. Can anyone tell me where this gray is hidden in the Theme?

[image]

Here is the code that produces an output show in the picture:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: const [
              Expanded(
                child: Icon(Icons.settings),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Icon(Icons.share),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Icon(Icons.photo),
              ),
            ]
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Addition:

I used @Yeasin Sheikh answer, but changed it a little to keep the selection of my primarySwatch color:

```
theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.purple).copyWith(
         iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.copyWith(
           color: Colors.black45,
         ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color of `leading`'s icon comes from [`ListTileThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTileThemeData-class.html)

To change leading color

```dart
theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  listTileTheme: Theme.of(context).listTileTheme.copyWith(
        iconColor: Colors.pink, // your color
      ),
),
```

> Default leading icon's color is [**`Colors.black45`**](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d719463489218f9de5f7b8b2237cb256f7617e9f/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1087) for `Brightness.light`

You can check it [on source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d719463489218f9de5f7b8b2237cb256f7617e9f/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1087).

To change `icon`'s color using theme, do

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.copyWith(
          color: Colors.black45,
        ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A look in the source code helped me to understand, why the color there is grey (Colors.black45). It is hardcoded in ListTile and does not come from any ThemeData, which is strange for me. That is why I did not find it in ThemeData. It is important for me to get it from ThemeData, because I might change the primarySwatch or switch to Brightness.dark. In that case I do not want the color to be fixed. However, in this case, it seems I do not have an option.

Answer (score 0):

color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

In this Line click on ctrl + primaryColor,
You will be Headed to theme_data page and there you can change your theme color according to your convience.

Answer (score 0):

try this
iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Icon(Icons.share),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Icon(Icons.photo),
            ),
          ]),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Add the following code into ThemeData

```
iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey)
```